# achartengine moveable line chart

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

i just create a new chart with achartengine and i notice that when i move the chart it go over the x and y axis. thanks to Dan this problem solve by update my achartengine to 1.1.0 ver.
anyway i saw that this problem has been solve at the achartengine demoes but i can't understead why it doesn't fix the problem at my chart.

[image]

i guess it something that i do wrong, my xml code is :

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rlMyChartsGridDown"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/rlMyChartsTopGrid"
android:background="@drawable/weeks_grid_down" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     />
```

my java code is:

```
    public GraphicalView weightView(Context context) {

        manageData = new ManageData(context);
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("The day");
        TimeSeries maxSeries = new TimeSeries("Max Weight");
        TimeSeries minSeries = new TimeSeries("Min Weight");

        int count = 0;
        float sum = 0;
        float max = 0;
        int preWeek = 0;

            manageData.open();
            cursor = manageData.getProfile();
            manageData.close();

            if ((cursor.moveToFirst()) && (cursor.getCount() != 0)) {
            weightUnit = cursor.getString(C_PROFILE_WEIGHT_UNIT);
            weight = cursor.getFloat(C_PROFILE_WEIGHT);
            bmi = cursor.getFloat(C_PROFILE_BMI);
            weightGain();
            cursor.close();
            minSeries.add(0,weight);
            maxSeries.add(0,weight);

            minSeries.add(12,weight+1);
            maxSeries.add(12,weight+2);
            minSeries.add(42,weight+minWeight);
            maxSeries.add(42,weight+maxWeight);
            }   


        manageData.open();
        Cursor cursor = manageData.getDiaryInfo();
        manageData.close();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            preWeek = cursor.getInt(DIARY_WEEK);
        }

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            if ((cursor.getInt(DIARY_WEEK) == preWeek)
                    && (cursor.getFloat(WEIGHT) != 0)) {
                count++;
                sum = sum + cursor.getFloat(WEIGHT);

                cursor.moveToNext();
            } else {
                if (count != 0) {
                    series.add(preWeek, sum / count);

                    if (max < sum / count) {
                        max = sum / count;
                    }
                }
                sum = 0;
                count = 0;
                preWeek = cursor.getInt(DIARY_WEEK);

                if (cursor.getFloat(WEIGHT) != 0) {
                    count++;
                    sum = sum + cursor.getFloat(WEIGHT);
                }

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        if (max < sum / count) {
            max = sum / count;
        }
        series.add(preWeek, sum / count);
        cursor.close();

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        dataset.addSeries(minSeries);
        dataset.addSeries(maxSeries);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        // Customization Weight line
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(0xff154916);
        renderer.setLineWidth(3);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        // Customization maxWeight line
        XYSeriesRenderer rendererMax = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererMax.setColor(0xff8EC239);
        rendererMax.setLineWidth(2);

        // Customization minWeight line
        XYSeriesRenderer rendererMin = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererMin.setColor(0xffF7931E);
        rendererMin.setLineWidth(2);


        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 35, 20, 20 });
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(color);

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererMax);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererMin);

        mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(18);
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);

        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
//      mRenderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);

        mRenderer.setXTitle("Week");
        if(weightUnit.equals("kg")){
        mRenderer.setYTitle("Weight (kg)");
        } else {
            mRenderer.setYTitle("Weight (lb)");
        }
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);   
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(0xff418614);

        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(5);
//      mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
//      mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(43);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        if(max>maxWeight + weight){
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max + 10);
        } else {
            mRenderer.setYAxisMax(maxWeight + weight + 10);
        }
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);

        return ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer);

    }
```

my main java code is:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.tbMyChartsWeight:
    tbMyChartsWeight.setChecked(true);
    tbMyChartsWaist.setChecked(false);
    tbMyChartsMood.setChecked(false);

    line = new LineGraph();
    gView = line.weightView(this);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    layout.removeAllViews();
    layout.addView(gView);
    return;
case R.id.tbMyChartsWaist:
    tbMyChartsWeight.setChecked(false);
    tbMyChartsWaist.setChecked(true);
    tbMyChartsMood.setChecked(false);

    line = new LineGraph();
    gView = line.waistView(this);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    layout.removeAllViews();
    layout.addView(gView);
    return;
case R.id.tbMyChartsMood:
    tbMyChartsWeight.setChecked(false);
    tbMyChartsWaist.setChecked(false);
    tbMyChartsMood.setChecked(true);

    line = new LineGraph();
    gView = line.mentalView(this);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    layout.removeAllViews();
    layout.addView(gView);
    return;
default:
    break;
}
```

}

i hope someone can help me with that 
and i'm sorry for my bad english
thanks for you all :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a transparent background. You can fix this by using other background type or don't set any background.

Comment: hi again Dan and thanks for your help. it realy work like a charm for me but i use transparent background only because i got my own custom background that i would like to importe. is there any way to have my custom background and also don't have the problem that i got? thanks again.

Comment: One thing that you could do would be to set all margins to 0 and don't use axis and labels.